# Why do I have to use "this" to call an extension method from within the extended class?

Tags: .net, extension-methods

I've written dozens of extension methods and they all work as expected.  But this is the first time I ran into using an extension method in this context.

```
public static class ControllerExtensions
{
    public static RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction<TController>(
        this Controller controller
        , Expression<Action<TController>> action
      ) where TController : Controller
    {
      RouteValueDictionary routeValuesFromExpression = 
        ExpressionHelper.GetRouteValuesFromExpression<TController>(action);

      return new RedirectToRouteResult(routeValuesFromExpression);
    }
}
```

Looks normal enough, right?  But within my controllers, I cannot access this extension method by typing.  Instead, I have to prefix it with the keyword "this".  For example:

```
// This does not work, I get a compiler error because
// RedirectToAction has no overload for the generic.
//
return
  RedirectToAction<MembershipController>(
     c => c.RegisterSuccess(Server.UrlEncode(code) ));

// But, this does work?!?!
//
return
  this.RedirectToAction<MembershipController>(
     c => c.RegisterSuccess(Server.UrlEncode(code) ));
```

Very odd.  Perhaps it is because I am within the instance object I am extending?  The "controller" instance that is?

Sure enough, I was able to duplicate it in a simple console app:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = new TestClass();
        x.Go<String>();
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public void Go()
    {
    }

    public void NextMethod()
    {
        // compiler error.  :(
        Go<String>();

        // works!
        this.Go<String>();
    }
}

public static class TestExtension
{
    public static string Go<T>(this TestClass theClass)
    {
        return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

So why does 'this.' work?

Comment: This has nothing to do with ASP.NET or MVC controllers. I changed the questions title and tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extension methods aren't part of the "default" lookup for members - you have to be using an expression of the form `Target.Method` before extension methods are checked. `this.Foo()` conforms to that requirement, so it works.

From section 7.5.5.2:

> In a method invocation (§7.5.5.1) of
>   one of the forms
>
> ```
> expr . identifier ( )
> expr . identifier ( args )
> expr . identifier < typeargs > ( )
> expr . identifier < typeargs > ( args ) if the normal processing of the
> ```
>
> invocation finds no applicable
>   methods, an attempt is made to process
>   the construct as an extension method
>   invocation.

Admittedly all that says is "the compiler is following the spec" rather than the reason why the spec was written that way... I don't know whether there *is* any specific reason, although the fact that you can invoke both instance members *and* static members using just `Method()`  (instead of specifying either an instance or a type) may be relevant.

Comment: You could argue, for example, that extension methods are supposed to support adding additional functionality to existing classes you don't control - if your object relied upon a particular extension method, then it should be built in to the main class definition, rather than rely upon a weak and potentially breakable dependency.

Comment: Thank you both for the reply and comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think is because of how extension methods works.

When you write Go(), the compiler assumes that Go is a method in the current class, which isn't.

Extension methods are 'attached' to a instance, and you specify the instance  using the this keyword.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Jon actually answered it correctly by specifying that the compiler is working from the spec in form of Target.Method.